# Excel conditional formatting count color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-statements, highlighting

I've been searching, and finding, information regarding conditional formatting and counting the colors. However, I have not been able to figure out how to do what I want.

In text:
I fetch data from the internet which I add in a 15 row x 20 column matrix (in 8 different sheets). I then want to highlight the top three values green and bottom three red per column and finally count all green/red per row.
Basically like this;

[image: screenshot]

(Eventhough I'm using values 1-10 in the picture above, it can be anything. It's the top/bottom three that's of interest.)

Problem with what I've found on counting colors that are conditionally formatted is that the conditions are to simple (i.e above value x, between x and y, and so on), so I cannot find a way to do this (ish).
I haven't tried it yet, but I guess I can evaluate a formula and conditionally formatting the cell based on the result of the evaluation. However, it seems then that I would need a formula per cell to do this which isn't something I want to do...
Example (based on screen shot):

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A3));A3<=SMALL(A$3:A$12;3))
```

and then:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A4));A4<=SMALL(A$3:A$12;3))
```

all the way to:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F12));F12<=SMALL(F$3:F$12;3))
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Some links I've checked (could only add one...):
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(LARGE(A$1:A$15;COUNTIF(A$1:A$15;MAX(A$1:A$15))+2)<=A1;1;0)
```

That's the formula if the first cell of your datas is at cell A1.

Copy the formula into an empty cell with enough space to extend it in a 15*20 matrix.

Then sum up all the rows and you will have you desired result ;)

You can hide the columns used to calculate the final result if you want !

To do the same for smallest values you just have to use `SMALL` instead of `LARGE`, and change the criteria of the `COUNTIF` :

```
=IF(SMALL(A$1:A$15;COUNTIF(A$1:A$15;MIN(A$1:A$15))+2)>=A1;1;0)
```

You can also use those formulas as an expression for your conditional formatting

Edit : screenshot of how it should look like

[image: g]

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I'd end up with two 15x20 matrices, one that I could hide. And then conditionally format the data matrix with input from the hidden matrix ?

Comment: And also add the hidden matrix rows...I'll test this tomorrow :)

Comment: The formula I gave you above is just used to compute the sum of each row. It takes value "1" when the related cell is one of the 3 max values of the column, otherwise it returns "0". You will end up with 3 matrix of 15*20 per dataset : 1 which is the original datas, 1 to  compute max value sum per row and a last for the min value sum per row. You can still use conditional formatting to make it more visual but that's purely aesthetical.

Comment: OK, it's not beautiful, but it works. I had hoped to count the colors but gets it done. I made a slight change though code is just : `=IF(A3>=LARGE(A$3:A$12;3);1;0)` 
This will only count the three top values. I.e if the top three is 10, only the three 10s will be counted.

Thanks a lot for helping me! :)